# Access a flash object from jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using swfobject 2 to dynamically embed my flash... let's call my object "swfContent"

I have tried to use $('swfContent') and $("#swfContent") to access my swf object, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the object ID "swfContent"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the underlying DOM object from the jQuery wrapper.

The easiest for that is to use jQuery's array-like index access.

```
$("#swfContent") // jQuery wrapper
$("#swfContent")[0] // underlying dom object
```

Try those 2 statements in firebug's command line to see the difference.